# SQL Server query hangs on first execution

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a .NET application using an SQL Server backend. There are deployments using all versions of SQL Server from 2008 to 2017 on clients running Windows 7 through to 10. Both 32 and 64 bit systems are used. Mostly the application runs as standalone with server and client on the same machine. Some deployments use Windows Server 2012.

There is one such instance (Windows 7, 32 bit, SQL Server 2014 SP2 CU10) where the first time a query is executed via a stored procedure, it hangs for about 10-15 seconds. Subsequent executions occur instantaneously. It is a simple SELECT COUNT(*) query that typically returns a value of 0-2 using the ExecuteScalar method. I cannot replicate this particular issue on any other machine. What is it that might be causing this to occur in an isolated instance?

Comment: Are you certain that you are not seeing a cache warm and subsequently being leveraged for better performance?

Maybe you are seeing an application page in because of the query's results hitting it, which is causing the delay?

Comment: How many rows is it counting?

Comment: @kalaolani I'm not so knowledgeable on the inner mechanisms of SQL Server to know whether this behaviour is by design for better performance but if this were the case then why am I seeing this only in isolated instance? I don't believe that anything else going on at the same time that might be causing this delay.

Comment: @MJH Whilst it may be querying tables with thousands of rows, the result of the COUNT query only ever returns between 0 and 2 rows.

Comment: Can you paste the query into your question and, if possible, provide some sample data?

Comment: @MJH It's a simple SELECT COUNT(*) query on a single table with a WHERE clause filter.